# What is the point of passing keywords equal to `None` as parameters in a function?

Tags: python, null, keyword, nonetype

I am trying to translate a [Python Voronoi Generator](https://github.com/jansonh/Voronoi/blob/master/DataType.py) to Java but I am not very familiar with keyword arguments and I am confused by the keyword argument that is written as a parameter of a function.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195391/why-a-calling-function-in-python-contains-variable-equal-to-value), but it only covers calling arguments, not defining them.

It seems like the function is just setting `a` and `b` to None. I don't understand why that is necessary. Why not just type `None` instead of using parameters like that?

*What is the point of using keyword parameters equal to None in function definitions?*

**The function:**

```
class Arc:
    p = None
    pprev = None
    pnext = None
    e = None
    s0 = None
    s1 = None

    def __init__(self, p, a=None, b=None):
        self.p = p
        self.pprev = a
        self.pnext = b
        self.e = None
        self.s0 = None
        self.s1 = None
```

Comment: Don't create a lot of class variables (i.e. static variables) only to immediately shadow them in `__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's not my code.

Comment: @LuminousNutria FYI: class members don't need to be declared in Python (they can be in `__slots__` but mostly aren't).  the lines doing e.g. `p = None` at the top are a bit of an anti-pattern and indicative of somebody who doesn't know the language.  the repo you pointed to links to a [C++ version](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~mbrubeck/voronoi.html) that looks more idiomatic

Comment: @SamMason well, and that was exactly my point. It is important to understand, not only do members not need to be declared, **there are no variable declarations in Python**, and exactly as you say, seeing code as the above makes it look like someone is writing Java/C++ in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I see. Thanks. I thought it looked weird too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yup, mostly agreed, but it's slowly changing with things like type hints.  Also, `nonlocal` and `global` affects a variable's scope, and scope is pretty tied to type declarations in other languages.

Comment: @SamMason type hints not really. Python is not going to become a statically typed language, and type hints change nothing about the semantics of Python. The global and nonlocal statements are close to variable declarations, but still, not really. I would call them more like "directives", since doing `global foo` doesn't create a variable `foo`, it does nothing with the identifier, it just changes the bytecode to one that checks for a global name instead of a local name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keyword arguments can have a default value. In this case, the default value of `a` and `b` are `None`. This means that when these arguments aren't passed into the function, `a` and `b` are set to `None`.

Example:

```
def func(a=None):
    print(a)
func()
>>>None
```

But if you do something like this:

```
def func(a):
    print(a)
func()
>>>TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def __init__(self, p, a=None, b=None):
```

That line is defining the `__init__` method, which you can think of as a constructor for the class. It's not calling the method.

Setting `a` and `b` equal to `None` in the method definition makes `None` their default value. This makes them optional when you call the method. (So you can call the method with 1, 2, or 3 parameters.) If you don't pass in values for `a` and `b`, `None` will be used. It's common in Python to use optional parameters in place of overloading methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is a concept called **default value**.

Using this syntax, the caller can choose whether to specify a value for every such argument or use the default one.

Suppose you have a method that has a default behavior, but you want to reserve the possibility to change it willingly. This give you this power.

Consider the following example:

```
def custom_method(msg, prefix=None):
  tag = prefix if prefix else ''
  print(tag + msg)
```

Now, as a user of this API, you can choose to use a prefix, or avoid it:

```
custom_method('Dude', 'Hi')
# Prints 'Hi Dude'
```

Or:

```
custom_method('Dude')
# Prints 'Dude'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Python syntax for *default* arguments, or optional argument.

Arguments which are declared with a default value, will receive that default value if they are not passed in the function call, and will receive what is passed in the other case.

Here `Arc(p)` is the same as `Arc(p, None, None)`, but you could use:

```
a1 = Arc(p)
a2 = Arc(p, a1)
```

and then `a2.pprev` will be `a1`.

But there are some caveats with [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3545273)... be careful with them or better avoid them until you are more proficient at Python.