# None keyword parameter

Tags: python

In Python (assuming a function parameter's default value is `None`),
is there any difference between ***passing in the keyword parameter

(when calling the function) as*** `None`, and ***not passing it in at all***?

I just want to make sure there isn't some subtle semantic difference between the two.

I am talking about this one in particular [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

and the `p0` parameter.

Comment: It depends on how exactly the function is declared.

Comment: "The None keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point of passing keywords equal to \`None\` as parameters in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220977/what-is-the-point-of-passing-keywords-equal-to-none-as-parameters-in-a-functio)

Comment: What do you mean it depends? I am talking about this one in particular https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html and the `p0` parameter.

Comment: @peter.petrov - in that scipy example, take a look at [these lines in the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/ab1c0907fe9255582397db04592d6066745018d3/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L704-L713). the function takes different paths if certain values are `None`, but that's up to the developer.

Comment: @jakub OK, thanks... But `p0` will be `None` no matter if I pass it in as `None` or not pass it in at all, is that correct?

Comment: Is your question "Does it make a difference if I pass None as argument if it already is the default value for the parameter", well, no, it doesn't. `None is None`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yeah, I think that's a better formulation of my question.

Comment: @peter.petrov - yes, `p0` will be `None` if you pass it in or not, because the default is `None` in the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very big difference:

```
def f(x=3):
    print(x)

def g():
    print("OK")

def h(x):
    print(x)
```

`f()` outputs `3`, while `f(None)` outputs `None`.

`g()` outputs `OK`, while `g(None)` raises a `TypeError`.

`h()` raises a `TypeError`, while `h(None)` outputs `None`.

---

Put briefly, using `None` indicates *semantic* absence, not *syntactic* absence.

Comment: Thanks. But the 2nd example is not what I have in mind. The function does have some argument e.g. `p0` and I am talking about not passing it or versus passing it in with `None` value.

Comment: The second example demonstrates that passing `None` when no argument is an error. Similarly (and what I should add to the answer) is that passing no value when expecting an argument without a default value is an error.

Comment: Thanks for the details in the 3 scenarios... I think that's the explanation I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass anything, the value will be changed to the default value specified. If you pass None, then it will not use the default.

```
def foo(bar='foobar'):
    print(bar)

foo()
foo(bar=None)
```

Outputs:

```
foobar
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need `key` parameter in your function ;

If you do not pass a `key` parameter, you won't be able to access `key` at all in your keyword arguments ({ KeyError`)

If you pass `key`as `None`, the `value of` key`in your keyword arguments will be`None`.